# How do I get metadata values for an AWS S3 object using Powershell?

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-s3

I'm trying to create a powershell script to get the Metadata Key/Value pair for a set of s3 files. Each file has the `x-amz-meta-build-id` metadata key with a value, verified in the console.

I have no problem getting the key, but the value is nowhere to be seen. I'm using the [AWS Powershell documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/items/Get-S3ObjectMetadata.html).

Here's my code:

```
Import-Module -Name AWS.Tools.Common
Import-Module -Name AWS.Tools.S3

# Use Set-AWSCredential to set the profile with access key and secret key
Set-AWSCredential -StoreAs $profileName -AccessKey $accessKey -SecretKey $secretKey -SessionToken $sessionToken

# gets a bunch of s3 files
$s3Contents = Get-S3Object -BucketName $s3 -ProfileName $profileName

foreach ($file in $s3Contents) {
    $fileName = $file.Key
    $fileDetail = Get-S3ObjectMetadata -BucketName $s3 -ProfileName $profileName -Key $fileName -Select Metadata
    $buildId = $fileDetail.Metadata.Keys["x-amz-meta-build-id"]
    Write-Host "Build: $buildId"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re using [`-Select Metadata`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/items/Get-S3ObjectMetadata.html), which is essentially a shortcut to just `$fileDetail.Metadata`. This means only the `Metadata` property is being returned.

However, you’re still trying to access `$fileDetail.Metadata`, which will be a null array because `$fileDetail` is now the metadata *itself*, not the full object.

You're also accessing the collection wrong - you shouldn't use `$fileDetail.Keys[]`.

This will work:

```
$fileDetail = Get-S3ObjectMetadata `
    -BucketName $s3 `
    -ProfileName $profileName `
    -Key $fileName `
    -Select Metadata

$buildId = $fileDetail["x-amz-meta-build-id"]
Write-Host "Build: $buildId"
```